# Maven Assembly Plugin - Include classes from another module

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multimodule project and am trying to generate an assembled file in SubProject2 that includes some of its classes plus some DTOs defined in SubProject1. However, Proc.jar file only has Proc.class and com\myproy\spr\dto*.class, whereas SubProject1's files (com\myproy\dto*.class) are not included and cannot come up with a way to make it work.

Projects' layout:

```
Parent
|-pom.xml
|
SubProject1
|-pom.xml
|-src\main\java\com\myproy\dto
|-src\main\java\com\myproy\util
|
SubProject2
|-pom.xml
|-src\assembly\def.xml
|-src\main\java\com\myproy\spr
|-src\main\java\com\myproy\spr\dto
```

def.xml:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0
                        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>Proc</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target/classes</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>com/myproy/spr/Proc.class</include>
                <include>com/myproy/spr/dto/*.class</include>
                <include>com/myproy/dto/*.class</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

SubProject2->pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>distro-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
             <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/def.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
             </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: have you solved that? I have similar question

Comment: Na, sorry, still looking for a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I understand you incorrectly. You want some specific functionality which is in the SubProject1. And you want only this functionality (not more) and you can not include the whole SubProject1 as dependency.

So maybe, if I understand it correctly, you can extract this functionality in another project (something like Commons), and add it as dependency in SubProject1 and SubProject2.

Comment: To clear it up: SubProject1 is a Model project, containing DTO and enum classes used by a Web and Service modules. I only want some of those DTOs and enums into the assembled file. The reason is mainly that some DTOs contain dependencies to libraries I don't want to/can't include in the assembled file. As for your recommendation...I don't think is a good idea to create another project only for this. I'd end up with ParentProject, WebProject, ServiceProject, ModelProject1, ModelProject2... I expected there to be a clean way to do it directy with Maven. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't add the project as a jar dependency ?¿.

Comment: I can't do that. The point is that I'm generating a jar that contains a DB2 stored procedure to be installed in DB2. If I included the whole jar there would be many other dependencies that should be added as well. I'd like to include only a small subset of the project's classes